# NullPointerException on Configuration/Application tab for Weblogic Deployment page on weblogic console

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic

I have an application where I was supposed to get rid of all EJBs and replace with Hibernate. Well, all that is taken care of in the original application and works well. I wanted to create a new project with the modified source code, create a war file instead of ear file. The new project builds well, deploys well (visible from some print statements which get executed as the application is deployed), but gives 404 when I do localhost:7001/index.jsp. Doing localhost:7001/index.html works well.
I login to weblogic console, go to Deployments, click the application name, click on Configuration tab and the Application tab, I see java.lang.NullPointerException. I looked over the internet but couldn't find a reason for the NPE and if it could be a reason that I am unable to access the jsps from the application? Can somebody enlighten me regarding this problem?

Comment: Share weblogic server's log after getting the NPE, it will help.

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel for at least looking at my question. Well, I don't see any changes in the log files after getting NPE. So, I am unable to figure out the cause for NPE. Could you say why I am able to access index.html and not index.jsp though they are at the same location?

Comment: Maybe looking at the log and stacktrace of the error will shed some light on this, but you should provide that info

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. The NPE is still there and I dont see anything in the logs. I don't have the rights to modify anything on the weblogic server so i dont know what to do. Good news is I can access the jsps now. There was some problem with the build because of which the jsps were not getting compiled.